# I found data on commits in the git, before 2005 (the year of its release) how to explain it?

Tags: python, git, wiki

As far as I understand from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git), git has existed since 2005,
how then did I find the [records that someone has made before](https://github.com/python/cpython/graphs/contributors)? (this is shown on the graph)

[this commit on github](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/7f777ed95a19224294949e1b4ce56bbffcb1fe9f#comments)

> ```
> gvanrossum committed on 10 Aug 1990
> ```

```
commit 7f777ed95a19224294949e1b4ce56bbffcb1fe9f
```

Comment: The author date and the commit date can be forged. It's also possible to specify a fake date for a commit. For example,  `GIT_COMMIT_DATE='1997-11-30 08:00:22 +0800' GIT_AUTHOR_DATE='1997-11-30 08:00:22 +0800' git commit`.

Comment: @ElpieKay I don’t think that the creator of python needed to do some kind of fake date :)

Comment: @Александр Of course. I just want to mention the possibility in other cases.

Comment: @ElpieKay in other cases there will not be much difference, it seems to me

Comment: I came here with the same question as you when looking at gvanrossum commit history on python repo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `cpython` source code had been using a [centralized version control system](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0374/#rationale) (VCS; first CVS, now Subversion) before it migrated to a distributed one. After PyCon 2009 [it was decided](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0374/#decision) to migrate to Mercurial. The commit history [was not lost](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0385/#history-management).

In 2015, [it was migrated again](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0512/#migration-plan) from Mercurial (hg.python.org) to GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily it had to be done on another VCS.... there are revisions that are pre any-vcs.... and it  can be done through using environment variables. There's one for commit time and another for author time.... and then you can go pretty far back in time.

https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo

Comment: I am not familiar with all these things, like VCS, I just realized, earler he saved changes using another application / service, and then switched to github

Comment: It!s ok... just wanted to point out that you will find stuff that predates any vcs.